# FTP Glob won't work

Tags: batch-file, ftp, glob

I have a problem with ftp via command line.

This is how I run the ftp file:

```
ftp -i -s:backup.ftp
pause
```

And this is my ftp file:

```
open HOST
USER
PASS
mget *.json
disconnect
quit
```

I am getting an error: no such file or directory. However if I change the * by a specific filename, it will work. As you can see, I didn't turn globbing off.

Also, when I connect to another ftp server, globbing does work. It seems like this ftp server blocks globbing or something. Anyone an idea??

Comment: Show us output from `ftp.exe` with `-d` (debug) switch. Ideally for both servers. If you have an access to the problematic server log, show us that too.

Comment: Note that `glob` command (and `-g` switch) applies to local files only anyway.

Comment: @Paul What sense does it have? The script obviously expects auto-login, as there's username and password just after the `open` command.

Comment: @ Martin Prikryl what do you mean with local files (sorry i am noob :D)

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/YFqpeEm) and here is the output with -d. It's in Dutch, but the last error translated is something like: can't find list with external files

Comment: Thanks for the output. What does a `ls` command output? Can you post the same output from the other server?